# Check for Lowercased First Character in String Value for MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

In my MariaDB environment I want to check to see if there are any values in the table "contacts" and the column "firstname", where the first letter in the string value is lower case. My question is: will this do the trick?

```
  SELECT * FROM contacts
  WHERE (firstname) LIKE '%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support syntax `[...]` with `LIKE`.

You can also use the following condition to check if the first character of firstname is lowercased:

```
BINARY lower(left(firstname, 1)) = left(firstname, 1)
```

Another option is to use a regex (shorter to write and easier to understand):

```
BINARY firstname RLIKE '^[a-z]'
```

Please note that both expressions will not use an existing index on `firstname`, since functions or regexes comes into play.

Comment: Very helpful. And a good reminder on the left side %. Thanks @GMB.

Comment: Does MariaDB support `[...]` with LIKE?

Comment: @forpas: you are sure right, it doesn't... I started with the other options, and then added that part. Just removed it.

Comment: This works for me in MariaDB: `      SELECT * FROM contacts
      WHERE (firstname) LIKE '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%';`

Comment: @Ademo: it doesn't seem to work in [this MariaDB 10.2 db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0f59efb912df58d318cc1b56a4939fde)

Comment: I am running the query via MySQL Workbench against a MariaDB database and I get the data I expect, as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is what I know about MariaDB's LIKE operator: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/like/. @Ademo are you sure you are using MariaDB?

Comment: I am sure, yes. But to be safe I will use the 'BINARY lower...' option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work in general, I believe you have to cast to binary:

```
cast(firstname as binary) rlike '^[a-z]'
```

Or:

```
cast(left(firstname, 1) as binary between 'a' and 'z'
```